# Regular expression: match youtube links, but not youtube embed code

Tags: regex, youtube

Could you help me, please. I need regular expression that match string like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eE4qPqMYsp8
```

but not this:

```
<object width="500" height="700"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/eE4qPqMYsp8&amp;hl=ru&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/eE4qPqMYsp8&amp;hl=ru&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent" width="500" height="700">
```

I have this code:

```
%(?:(http://){0,1}(www.){0,1}youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|(http://){0,1}(www.){0,1}youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%
```

I don't know  how to exclude some parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about an expression like this:

```
(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?youtube\.com/watch.+?\bv=[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

You can certainly add in more options (e.g. `(?:-nocookie)`), but it might be specific enough like this already.